Was the 1958 FIFA world cup broadcast in its entirety?
It is easy to find the of the 1958 World Cup Final (Brazil vs Sweden) on the internet. However, I can't find the other matches, even the Brazilian ones, which featuring the champion might be easier to find.
Was the 1958 FIFA World Cup broadcast in its entirety, or did they just broadcast the final?

According to Wikipedia [bold italic emphasis mine]:

Almost all the matches kicked off simultaneously in each of the three rounds of the group phase, as did the quarter-finals and semi-finals. The exceptions were Sweden's three group matches, all of which were televised by Sveriges Radio; these started at other times so Swedes could attend other matches without missing their own team's. Apart from these, one match per round was televised, and relayed across Europe by the European Broadcasting Union (EBU). Many Swedes bought their first television for the World Cup.

So, it looks like at most two matches per round were televised. Based on my own experiences working in the broadcast industry, I find it unlikely the host broadcaster (presumably SR) would have the resources or technology to televise all those simultaneous matches.
Remember, until 2002 the host broadcast duties were performed by one of the national broadcasters of the host country. (And when I write "one of", I mean "the", because in 1958, many countries had only one broadcaster.) So, you can imagine that, shortly after WW II, with 1950s technology, and a relatively small broadcaster like Swedish Radio, it would have been impossible to televise all those up to 7(!!!) simultaneous matches.
Nowadays, there are specific companies which specialize in providing host broadcast services for large sports events, such as the aptly named Host Broadcast Services, which is the host broadcaster of choice for FIFA (World Cup, Women's World Cup, and several others), UEFA (Euro), FIS (Alpine and Nordic Ski World Championships), and some others (e.g. Rugby World Cup, Roland Garros), or Olympic Broadcasting Services.
Unfortunately, this paragraph of the Wikipedia article does not have an individual reference. However, most references in the article are from this book released for the 50th anniversary:

Norlin, Arne (2008). 1958: När Folkhemmet Fick Fotbolls-VM. Malmö: Ross & Tegner. ISBN 978-91-976144-8-1.

Also, don't forget this was just barely after Sputnik. There was no way to broadcast any of the matches outside of the EBU's network. In the 1950s, the way a match like this would be "broadcast" in Brazil is a Brazilian reporter sitting in the stadium, writing down everything that happens, then after the match is finished, race to a public telephone and call his station to retell the match on air.
